# What is wrong with this Excel formula to sum() next 2 columns in the same row?

Tags: excel, formula

I did try to enter in a cell formula:

```
=SUM(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1):ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+2))
```

Intention is summing next 2 cell in the same row.
But the spreadsheet complains with error on it!

Used functions: `ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()+1)`. Work fine but together - not!
In B7 cell:

(I need to write a generic formula that is independent from location and calculates the sum of the next tho cell in the same row.
I am not interested in specific addresses or in a way to copy any specifically written formula across a spreadsheet.
I need a formula that works independently from a location!
Is it possible in Excel at all?)
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel: list ranges targeted by INDIRECT formulas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493/excel-list-ranges-targeted-by-indirect-formulas)

Comment: The question is different in that one but the result is the same - look into the INDIRECT formula.

Answer (score 1):

`ADDRESS` returns address as a string. You cannot `SUM` it because `SUM(A2:A3)` is very different from `SUM("A2:A3")`.

You could look into `SUM(INDIRECT("A2:A3"))`, but you should not, for the mere reason that Excel's formulas are already relative unless made absolute.

If you want to sum two cells to the right of B7, enter `=SUM(C7:D7)` to B7. The formula will change if you copy it to another cell.

If you meant to enter the formula with a macro, then use the [R1C1 notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27023096/11683) and enter `=SUM(RC[1]:RC[2])`.

Answer (score 0):

sorry im dont speak english , but a have what you need

```
= SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()+1);":"; ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()+2))))
```

Regards